# spring initializer blocks spring security login

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-security

In a project I'm developing in early stages whenever I add to the `web.xml` the `ContextLoaderListener` with its params, the custom login, nor the default login of spring-security loads, and it displays a 404 error. While without it the login loads fine.

Currently I am using Hibernate 5, Spring 5.0.7, and implementing Spring Security.

Help will be appreciated.
Thank you.

This is the method inside the class that extends `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    http
    .authorizeRequests()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
    .formLogin()
        .loginPage("/Login.xhtml").permitAll();
    http.formLogin().failureUrl("/Login.xhtml?error=true");

    http.formLogin().defaultSuccessUrl("/test.jsp",true);
}
```

the  `.formLogin().loginPage("/Login.xhtml").permitAll();` 
can also be substituted by `.and().httpBasic();`

then inside Webcontent-Web-Inf I have a `web.xml` where I add the listener of spring to initialize it

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<!-- PARAMETRO QUE INDICA NOMBRE Y RUTA DEL FICHERO DE CONFIGURACION DE 
    SPRING -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:com/spring/modelo.xml</param-value>
</context-param>`
```

`modelo.xml` contains all the mapping for hibernate etc...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-15"?>
<beans default-autowire="byName" default-lazy-init="true"
xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.3.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.3.xsd

    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

<!-- COMPONENTE DE LECTURA DE PROPERTIES -->
<bean id="gestor_properties"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <!-- RUTA Y NOMBRE DE PROPERTIES A LEER -->
    <property name="location"

        value="classpath:com/spring/datos-conexion.properties" />
</bean>

<!-- ************ ZONA DE ACCESO A LA BASE DE DATOS ************ -->
<!-- CONEXION A LA BASE DE DATOS -->

<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="configLocation"
        value="classpath:com/atos/hibernate/hibernate.cfg.xml">
    </property>
</bean>


<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager" />


<tx:annotation-driven
    transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<!-- **** DATASOURCE REQUERIDO POR TRANSACTION MANAGER **** -->
<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${spring.datasource.driver}" />
    <property name="url" value="${spring.datasource.url}" />

    <property name="username" value="${spring.datasource.nombre}" />
    <property name="password" value="${spring.datasource.clave}" />
</bean>



<!-- PAQUETES CON ANOTACIONES PARA SPRING PARA LA GESTION DEL MODELO -->


    <context:component-scan
    base-package="com.atos.hibernate.modelo" />

    <context:component-scan
    base-package="com.atos.hibernate.dao" />

    <context:component-scan
    base-package="com.atos.hibernate" />

    <context:component-scan
    base-package="com.atos.dao_ext" />

    <context:component-scan
    base-package="com.atos.util" />
```

When i test exclusively my back-end part of the project, it works perfectly with hibernate and all the queries i command to do with hibernate etc work fine.

But when i implement spring security the sadness arrived...

Comment: how do you load class with security configuration extended from `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` ??

Comment: @VladimirVagaytsev  with another class that extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer                                        public SecurityWebApplicationInitializer() {
  super(SecurityConfig.class);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, the fact that i already had a contextloader for springframework interfered with the new context spring security was loading. This is solved by removing @configure annotation and removing the constructor from `package com.atos.springSecurity;

import org.springframework.security.web.context.AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer;

public class SecurityWebApplicationInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {

}
    `